# setSelectionColor() not affecting select(nodes) color

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Calling

```
viewer.setSelectionColor(new THREE.color('0xff0000'); // set the color to red
viewer.select(1); // select the entire model
```

selects the entire model, but keeps the default blue selection color.  Clicking on the model then selects a component and colors it red, so the `setSelectionColor` is working, but only for mouse clicks, not for `select()` calls?

Mouse click events seem to be calling `select()` internally, so I would expect them both to use the same color.

`setSelectionColor()` will change the color of the currently selected-by-mouse component, so it isn't a race condition.  Clicking on the model uses the red selection color, then using a button to trigger a `select` call returns to the blue.

It seems to be an issue in 2.12, 2.15 and 2.16.

Is there a different method for changing the colors of components that are selected through code rather than through mouse clicks?

Edit: appears to be fixed in 2.17

Comment: On my side, it's only not working on the root node with mouse clicking and `viewer.select`. I'm checking with our dev team and will get you back A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We apologize for any inconvenience caused.

This might be an issue of the Forge Viewer. It can be reproduced on my computer. We have logged it with the id `BLMV-772` in our internal case system for our dev team to allocate time to investigate. But there is no ETA, it might take some time. You can send the issue id `BLMV-772` to `forge.help@autodesk.com` to check updates anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not right. Replace your string:

`viewer.setSelectionColor(new THREE.color('0xff0000');`

with

`viewer.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(0xff0000);`